# Recording WAV files in safari and chrome yields different codecs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, record, wave

I am trying to do a text to speech app that uses the google transcoder service, i am trying to get my app to run on chrome and safari but i figured that they don't encode WAV files (the file i am using to hold the recording) the same way.

Chrome uses the MKA format and Safari uses the M4A format, the latter doesn't work for the google transcoder. I am trying to find a way to get Safari to output the same as chrome format but it seems it's the "apple" way.

is there a possible solution to not have to use a backend to convert all recordings to the same format ?

Here are 2 exmaples of the recordings tags : [Safari](https://www.metadata2go.com/result#j=1aaec1db-0c4a-4fcf-9790-41b6c69f5dec), [Chrome](https://www.metadata2go.com/result#j=acaa72e2-e09d-45ac-a0e6-ccfae0e5fe2b)